# Order Detail page get Order Item Collection When select any order in admin order grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

i have apply filter on order grid in admin page. Just all those order display in Admin Order Grid which is relate to current login admin products.

But when i click on any order row in grid then in Order detail page all order items are listed .
I want to show just those order item which is belong to current admin user products.
I have already save custom_attribute ("current_admin_id") in each product(**eav_attribute**) ,**quote_item,quote,sales_order** and **sales_order_grid**.

Just guid me little bit which event dispatch or which function return the order_items return in order detail page. if i get to known which calss->function return order collection then i will override and make custom.
Help me to find which and where the order_items collection that set in **order detail page.**